# Convert Data from MySQL to JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to convert data from my DB to JSON with a PHP script. 
Everything works great on my local environment (MAMP).
As soon as I am trying to put things together on my server, my JSON File is empty :(

What I have so far

my php script

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","angulardb") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));


$sql = "select * from postings";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));


    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;

    }




  $fp = fopen('menue.json', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
  fclose($fp);


  echo json_encode($emparray);

?>
```

By uploading this script to my server (& update the data), I receive an empty JSON file with no response.

Any Idea what can be wrong???
Is there additional configuration necessary on the server side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To me, this sounds like there is a problem with writing permission to the file/folder.

Comment: I added write pwemissions for the entire folder + subfolders

Comment: Does `echo $result;` return anything?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
got it .

the missing chsrset=utf8 caused my problem!

$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=db239256x2330361;host=mysql.webhosting38.1blu.de;***charset=utf8***","s239256_2330361","20dj93lpav+dd");